# Lambda Expression with a statement body can not been converted

Tags: c#, linq

I'am trying to get running total.

```
decimal currentTotal = 0;
var query = test
           .OrderBy(i => i.Date)
           .Select(i =>
           {
               currentTotal += i.Amount;
               return new
               {
                   Date = i.Date,
                   Amount = i.Amount,
                   RunningTotal = currentTotal
               };
           }
                  );
```

And I've got error in this line    `.Select(i =>` How could I resolve this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Lambda Expression with a statement body can not been converted

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are doing a query to Entity Framework or LINQ2SQL:

```
decimal currentTotal = 0;

var query = test
            .OrderBy(i => i.Date)
            .Select(i => new
            {
                    Date = i.Date,
                    Amount = i.Amount
            })

            // Above lines executed on SQL
            .AsEnumerable()
            // Below lines executed locally

            .Select(i =>
            {
                currentTotal += i.Amount;
                return new
                {
                    Date = i.Date,
                    Amount = i.Amount,
                    RunningTotal = currentTotal
                };
            }
        );
```

You can't execute your add to currentTotal on the SQL Server, so you use `AsEnumerable()` to execute it locally.

Explanation:

When you program with EF/LINQ2SQL, the query you build with `IQueryable<T>` is translated in the SQL language and executed on the SQL Server. So the `.OrderBy()` becomes a `ORDER BY`, all the `.Where()` become a `WHERE` and so on. Clearly if in the LINQ query you put something that can't be translated to SQL, then you get an exception when the query is translated. Now, there are two problems in your query.

For some limitations of C#, only expressions written without `{ ... }` [blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664737(v=vs.71).aspx) (and some other limitations... no `if`, no `return`, ...) can be translated to `Expression<Func<>>`. For this reason your program can't be compiled.

Even if it was possible to compile it directly, the SQL Server doesn't know anything of your `currentTotal` variable, so you would get a `NotSupportedException` at runtime.

The solution: you create a "legal" query with only the pieces that can be executed by SQL... You `.Select()` the columns you'll need. Then with `.AsEnumerable()` you tell the EF that from the `.AsEnumerable()` onward it mustn't translate the query to SQL, and must execute the query "locally". So the `.OrderBy()` and the first `.Select()` will be executed SQL-side, while the second `.Select()` (with the `currentTotal`) will be executed locally.

Comment: How do you know it's a query to Entity Framework or Linq2Sql?

Comment: First of all - it's EF. Second - I wanna to do it as IQueryable

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt What xanatos meant to say is that the OP is using a LINQ provider other than linq-to-objects, because `Enumerable.Select<T>` takes a delegate as argument, not an expression. Linq-to-sql, for example, uses an expression instead of a delegate (`Queriable.Select<T>`).

Comment: @dcastro: Aaaah, that makes sense, yes, although far from obvious how he came to that conclusion from the provided code, especially since the answer was posted 1 minute before the OP mentioned the actual error :)

Comment: @AlexGurskiy May I ask why? That step has to be done in memory anyway.

Comment: @willem after some hundred responses, you gain a sixth sense for problems 

Comment: Hm. I've run this code in LINQPad and it's work in query and work fine. And I can't understand: why it's work in one SQL query?

Comment: @AlexGurskiy Long explanation added

Answer (score -1):

**Error:Lambda Expression with a statement body can not been converted to an expression tree**

It means that you can't use lambda expressions with a "statement body" which is the case with linq2sql. which means you can only use simple expression after => operator